# AWS SMS with link in message body is not sent

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms

I am trying to send SMS through AWS SNS. Message body includes a URL to the webpage for user invite.

Messages work for Australia but when I send similar message to New Zealand, it fails.

If I remove URL from message body, SMS is sent otherwise it fails.

Here is the AWS cloudwatch log

```
{
    "notification": {
        "messageId": "..........",
        "timestamp": "2021-10-25 14:18:44.002"
    },
    "delivery": {
        "numberOfMessageParts": 1,
        "destination": "+64........",
        "priceInUSD": 0.12146,
        "smsType": "Transactional",
        "providerResponse": "Phone is currently unreachable/unavailable",
        "dwellTimeMs": 1011,
        "dwellTimeMsUntilDeviceAck": 3192
    },
    "status": "FAILURE"
}
```

Looking through AWS forums it says that one one the possibilities for this response can be invalid message body.

Interestingly if I add https://google.com in message body, SMS is sent.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this or find the exact constraints?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. All of a sudden all of our SMS failed to send (our texts include a link). I tried sending various links all failed to send; however, www.google